# UIWebView will not loadRequest inside a separate class file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIWebView` that is successfully being created dynamically from an included class file (I think... there are no errors being spit out). My function that creates this webview in the `Foo.m` class file is:

```
+(void) openWebView {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView setHidden:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    NSLog(@"Successful web open: ", url); 
  });
}
```

I do get a warning error message on the `setDelegate` line (it doesn't crash the app though) that reads:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'const Class' to parameter of type 'id:<UIWebViewDelegate>'

The problem is that while the `NSLog` does log the correct URL it is trying to open, the page actually never gets called (I can tell this because I have a PHP counter on that page that increments each time it is opened).

**So my questions are:**

1. Am I missing something in the .h file? I've added nothing there in
   respect to this new WebView
2. I feel like I am missing the object that `self` references to. It was also made mention [here in my precursor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495966/how-to-create-then-destroy-a-uiwebview-inside-a-class-file) to this one.
3. How can I check the response of the `loadRequest`

Sorry everyone, as you probably can figure out from my questions, Obj-C is a little new to me, but I am really struggling here and would appreciate the help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a class method (indicated by the `+` sign). `self` in a class method refers to the class itself, not an instance. The `delegate` of a `UIWebView` (or anything really) has to be an object though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `openWebView` method is a class method because of the `+` at the beginning.  For this reason, you don't have an object.  `self` in this case returns the class (hence the warning).  Perhaps you want `openWebView` to be an instance method, so change the `+` to `-` and then `self` will point to your instantiated object.

To check if the loadRequest worked, you implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate methods `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` in your delegate (ie Foo.m) and see if they get called.

Comment: Is there something I will need to add to my `Foo.h` file after changing the + to a -? I ask because I did that and now my app crashes.

Comment: How are you calling openWebView?  What error are you getting in the debugger?

Comment: I am calling it from within another method inside that same class file. 

    `-(void) startTheWebView {
      [...]
    }`

The error is **target does not implement selector...**

Comment: So you're calling it with `[self openWebView]` ?

Comment: It sounds like you are not implementing a method in class Foo that is required by being a UIWebViewDelegate.

Comment: `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(openWebView) withObject:nil]` I also tried it your way, and I also got the same type of error message in debugger.

Comment: Which selector does the target not implement?

Comment: -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** +[startTheWebView])

Comment: Ok, so the answer to why `loadRequest` is not working is that I do not have my delegate set correctly?

Comment: There may be other things wrong with your `loadRequest` as well.  Why don't you implement the delegate methods `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` in your delegate (ie Foo.m) and see if they get called.